# Transpose column to row

Tags: notepad++

How do I convert code from a column:

```
1
2
3
4
```

to in a row (with spaces):

```
1 2 3 4
```

using Notepad++ ?

Comment: If anyone wants to do the opposite, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/903352/how-do-i-convert-code-characters-from-a-row-to-column).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Select to suit, Search, Replace \r\n with 'space' (using Extended).

Notepad ++ puts a carriage return and a line feed at the end of each line (automatically when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed). These can be displayed if `Show All Characters` is toggled (the pilcrow – ‘¶’, like a reversed P) and in Extended Mode accessed with `\r` for *r*eturn and `\n` for *n*ew line. To substitute these two control codes with a space just place them in `Find what :` and hit <kbd>Space</kbd> in `Replace with :`:

[image: SU598241 example]

Comment: I try to use your way but it lost space between two character same 1234

Comment: Thank , I will do it with two step 1. replace \r\n by one string. After that replace string by space.

Comment: +1 because your name is "pnuts" and to give this answer a score of 10!

Answer (score 36):

Here's what I do for that :

1. `Ctrl + A`: selects all.
2. `Ctrl + J`: aligns them in a row.

Comment: I agree, this is the best answer.

Comment: This is nice, although it doesn't work as expected when there are multiple columns. I know it wasn't asked for by OP, I'm just saying.

Comment: to whoever wonders, this can be found under `Edit->Line Operations->Join Lines`