# Notepad++: Transpose list to specific number of columns

Tags: notepad++

This question is similar to: [Transpose column to row](https://superuser.com/questions/598241/transpose-column-to-row)

I want to change a list into a specific number of columns separated by commas.

So if I want 2 columns. I want to change this text:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

to

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
```

What would be the easiest, quickest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume, below is your file content,

```
LineA
LineB
LineC
LineD
LineE
LineF
```

You can achieve what you want to do in two steps,

- Use Text FX plugin or any other way to insert line numbers at the start of each line followed by a identifiable string that will not be used anywhere else on the file contents. I have chosen the string to be `START`. So, below will be the file content after line numbers are inserted,

```
1STARTLineA
2STARTLineB
3STARTLineC
4STARTLineD
5STARTLineE
6STARTLineF
```

(Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12036632/1261124) to see how to perform the same)

- Now, using `Replace` option with `search mode` as `Regular expression`, search for `^[0-9]*[1,3,5,7]START(.*)\r\n^[0-9]*[2,4,6,8,0]START(.*)` and replace it with `$1,$2`. The resultant content will be as below,

```
LineA,LineB
LineC,LineD
LineE,LineF
```