# How do I convert code/characters from a row to column

Tags: notepad++, notepad

How do I convert code/characters from a row:

1 2 3 4 5

to in a column:

1

2

3

4

5

using Notepad++ ?

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/598241/transpose-column-to-row) . That question refers to reverse of what you have asked but it will help.

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I move characters from a row to a column?

1. `Select` the line

[image]

2. `Search` > `Replace` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

[image]

3. Set `Find what` to a single <kbd>space</kbd>.
4. Set `Replace with` to `\r\n` (carriage return + line feed).
5. Enable `Regular expression`.
6. Click `Replace all`.
7. Click `Close`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this, but wanted to transpose each individual character in the row. This is what I ended up doing:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Find what: `(.)`
3. Replace with: `$1\r\n`
4. Search Mode: `Regular expression`
5. Click `Replace All`

It worked...and made me realize it was useless and how unreadable vertical text and spacing is actually.

Comment: This will also replace every spaces with a linebreak, that is not what is wanted.